# How to position a CSS triangle using ::after?

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I've created a div with a bottom arrow using ::after. Here is the HTML code:

```html
<div class="sidebar-resources-categories">Topics</div>
<div class="text-content">ok ok</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```css
.sidebar-resources-categories{
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.sidebar-resources-categories::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 42%;
    top: 100%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid #e8e8e8;
    clear: both;
}
```

Here is the result:

[image: Here is the result]

I would like the arrow to be at the very bottom of the grey div. I don't want to have the content between the div and the bottom arrow. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does this CSS triangle shape work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work)

Comment: Not a duplicate. This issue relates to positioning the `::after` pseudo-element, not building the triangle itself.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just add `position:relative` to the parent element `.sidebar-resources-categories`

http://jsfiddle.net/matthewabrman/5msuY/

explanation: the ::after elements position is based off of it's parent, in your example you probably had a parent element of the .sidebar-res... which had a set height, therefore it rendered just below it. Adding position relative to the .sidebar-res... makes the after elements move to 100% of it's parent which now becomes the .sidebar-res... because it's position is set to relative. I'm not sure how to explain it but it's expected behaviour.

read more on the subject: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: To be a little more informative, it has to do with the `position:absolute` and `top:100%` properties on .sidebar-resources-categories::after. An absolutely positioned element is placed according to the nearest parent that has `position:relative,` or the highest parent in the DOM (body). So you were placing the arrow's top edge at 100% of the parent element's height. When you add the position:relative to .sidebar-resources-categories, the arrow instead places 100% of that bar's height.

Comment: In regards to the jsfiddle, I would add margin-left: -20px; to the :after selector to fully center the arrow horizontally

Comment: Nice! How can I surround the rectangle plus triangle *ensemble* with a border? Using `box-shadow`? How would you do that?

Answer (score 22):

Add a class:

```
.com_box:after {
     content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 18px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid #000;
    clear: both;

}
```

Updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wrm4y8k6/8/

Answer (score 1):

You can set triangle using the `position` property as below:

```css
    .top-left-corner {
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        border-top: 0px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 55px solid transparent;
        border-left: 55px solid #289006;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
    }
```